# What is the best way to get current url string in an html a tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below block of code and I want to use javascript to check if current url string has "?mall", then I will add that to my href attribute in the  tag. What is the best way to go about it?

```
<div>
  <div>
    <a href="/" role="button">My Link</a>
       My Page
  </div>
  <div id="my-list"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This would check if the string `'mall'` in the query string (everything behind `?`).
If it is, it will try to locate the `<a>` tag with an `href="/"` attribute.

If that tag is found it adds `?mall` to the current `href` attribute value.

```
if (location.search.includes('mall')) {
  const anchor = document.querySelector('a[href="/"]');
  if (anchor) {
    anchor.href += '?mall';
  }
}
```